# Which CMS is a good option for a 4-page website with simple content management?

Tags: backend, content-management-system, web-frontend, static-site

I'm building a 4-page **flat-file-system** website for my friend using **HTML**, **CSS**, and basic **JavaScript** for the front end. My friend has very little ***coding knowledge***, so I'm looking for a **CMS** (***Preferably Open Source***) that will allow him to easily manage the content on the site, such as adding, editing, and deleting **text**, **images**, and simple **videos**. We already have web hosting, so I'm just looking for something that can be easily integrated into the existing website.

He dosen't need to change the general layout of the site, I just need to provide my friend with a simple and intuitive interface for managing the content. Can anyone recommend an easy to use and reliable **CMS** that would be well-suited for this type of website?

However, we are not a fan of **WordPress** and similar **CMS** platforms due to their complexity and bloatedness. I'm seeking recommendations for a ***standalone solution*** that is simple and straightforward, yet still provides the necessary features to manage content on a small website. I'm looking for something that is easy to use and has a minimal learning curve so that my friend can manage the content without any difficulty.

*Thank you in advance for your help!*

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Based on my extensive research of various **CMS** options, I highly recommend **WonderCMS** for this type of website. **WonderCMS** is a **flat-file-system CMS** that is lightweight and contains no database, which makes it a great choice for smaller websites or projects with limited resources. Additionally, **WonderCMS** comes with a number of useful ***plugins***, including a simple site editor that allows non-technical users to make updates to the website with ease.

For anyone who is interested in exploring this option further, I have included a link to the **WonderCMS** website below. I hope this proves to be helpful for anyone seeking a simple, user-friendly and lightweight solution.

> https://www.wondercms.com/